# wcs_get_subscriptions and update_manual not working

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm trying to toggle a subscription manual/auto renewal, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have the "Accept Manual Renewals" enabled in the settings and the code does execute as expected. The call is made via ajax:

```
session_start();
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require_once( '../../../wp-load.php' );
```

and the update function is:

```
    $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions(['subscriptions_per_page' => -1]);
    foreach((array)$subscriptions as $id => $subscription) {
        if ($desiredSubscriptionID == $id) {
            if ($subscription->is_manual()) { // always returns false
                // switch to auto
                $subscription->update_manual(false);
                $response["type"] = "auto";
            } else {
                // switch to manual
                $subscription->update_manual(true);  // returns true as it should
                $response["type"] = "manual";
            }
        }
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm just starting customizing the woocommerce pages

Answer (score 0):

fixed by updating the meta data directly:

```
update_post_meta($id, '_requires_manual_renewal', 'true');
```

instead of using the:

```
$subscription->update_manual(true);
```